# How to detect a period of inactivity in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to detect a period of user inactivity in my EmberJS application so that, after a certain duration I can call a `session.inValidate` method and revoke their authentication.

The only resource I have been able to find is an article [here](http://rajeeshcv.com/2014/06/12/EmberJS-How-to-Detect-User-Inactivity/) which I was advised in [an original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153327/how-to-add-a-property-to-the-app-object-in-an-emberjs-application?noredirect=1#comment93199271_53153327) is out of date and doesn't use current Ember concepts.

The out-of-date article suggested adding a property to the `App` object and updating the property on certain events like `mousemove` but I was unable to find a location to set this property correctly in either `app.js` or the config environment.

[ember-concurrency](http://ember-concurrency.com/docs/introduction) was recommended but after looking at some of the documentation I still don't understand where such code fits in an EmberJS application structure.

Unfortunately I'm stuck at a point before I can give a code sample. Any advice is appreciated.

Edit: As per @hernanvicente excellent question, I am defining inactivity as 'no user input'. So no `mousemove` or `key press` events within X period

Comment: How would you identify an user inactivity? No mouse movement? No transition? You could create a service to track the user's last activity, saving the datetime value would allow you  to ask every X seconds if there was a new user's activity.

Comment: That's a good point I should have covered, I've updated the original question. I thought a service might be appropriate on the parent route but I can't work out what that might look like in code, particularly with detecting events without using jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hard question here is what *activity* actually means. Generally I would advise against your idea. There is no way to know if the user is actually still looking on your page.

However if you really want to do *something* after the user hasn't done *something* for some amount of time the interesting question is where to place your code.

You have multiple options here, but probably not the worst option would be to use the application controller. You could also use a service, but then you need to use that service somewhere to initialize it. You could *also* just use a component.
If you want to couple this to authentication you could consider to use the existing `session` service.

However everything else is not really ember specific. You can just place some code in the application controllers `init` hook and access `document.addEventListener()`. Then you could just save a timestamp away and act accordingly.

To have a bit a nicer API for *waiting* you can utilize `ember-concurrency` with a `restartable` task:

```
didSomething: task(function * () {
  yield timeout(1000); // number of miliseconds to wait
  logout();
}).restartable(),
```

here `logout()` will be called, after the task hasn't been called for 1 second. A nice visual demonstration about [task concurrency and `restarable` can be found here](http://ember-concurrency.com/docs/task-concurrency).

[Here is an ember-twiddle showing a complete example](https://ember-twiddle.com/0359b1bf04e01b91bb5ad61b6f3f0525?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C).

Comment: Thank you for coming back to my quest @Lux and for providing the twiddle. I agree with your first point about user activity however my application displays sensitive data that shouldn't be left idle. This was the best solution I could think of. I'll play with your examples for a bit then accept the answer

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the example in the twiddle isn't suitable from Ember 3.5. Implementing it in the controller gives the following error `You attempted to access `didSomething.perform` (on `<(unknown mixin):ember290>`), but `didSomething` is a computed property.` The full error is [here](https://pastebin.com/qsDnAVRc)

Comment: Disregard the above comment. It does in fact work, I just had to change `this.didSomething.perform()` for this.get('didSomething').perform()

Comment: you're *sure* you are on 3.5? The error looks like you're pre `3.1`. The code only works with `3.1+`. Otherwise use `this.get('didSomething').perform()` as mentioned in the error

Comment: Nope, I was an idiot and had updated ember cli without updating the ember app. That's two solves in one answer.. thanks for your patience

Comment: Note: You don't need ember-concurrency here for a having a nice API. Just fire your function using [deboude() provided by ember runloop](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.5/functions/@ember%2Frunloop/debounce) on every user interaction. Every new user interaction will reset the timer until your function is executed. Way simpler IMO than yielding a timeout on an ember-concurrency task.